# Dedicated Centos 7.2/Plesk 12.5 server most services Fail on boot. dbus failure - Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little

Tags: centos, d-bus

Suddenly this Centos 7.2/Plesk 12.5 dedicated server restarted and never booted again. most services fail. i don't have ssh so i can only go through rescue system (Debian) and check the logs.
I didn't make any changes whatsoever for a long time but plesk keeps updating regularly.

As far as my search goes it seems that dbus fails and everything else follows. the whole things ends in a loop
i thought it could be a hardware failure so i asked the guys in Hetzner and they did a full hardware test. Everything came clean

I pasted part of my "messages" log on an original post in SO
[Dedicated Centos 7.2/Plesk 12.5 server most services Fail on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305481/dedicated-centos-7-2-plesk-12-5-server-most-services-fail-on-boot)
Any ideas?

thank you in advance

Comment: Can't find root? If you boot from some recovery media and mount the OS drive, can your /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and /etc/group files OK?

Comment: I booted rescue system, mounted md2. In /mnt/etc/ all 3 files exist. all 3 have one more file with dash like passwd-, shadow- etc. passwd file is empty.

Comment: I suggest that there is your problem. Have you got a backup of your passwd file?

Comment: is this the root pass ? i only have plesk backups, i don't think they include passwd file.

Comment: oh my! i just opened a passwd file from another server. how did all this data got deleted? is this an attack? and you are so right! it is modified 1 minute before the problem started

Comment: Yes!   restored passwd with passwd-  and yep the server is working again!
Thank you so very much Raman!!! (how can i pick your answer as ...THE answer :P ??)
Still, got any ideas how such thing could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the issue here is that pamd is having difficlty pasing the required authentication files i.e. /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/group and hence cannot find a root user. Some of the file may be missing.

Comment: any suggestions why such things can happen? thanks again.